# Действия над многоугольником

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне надо нарисовать с помощью кликов на форме многоугольник  Я многоугольник нарисовал. И надо сделать над ним следующие действия:

1. Повернуть его около неподвижной точки
2. Маштабировать его
3. Зеркально отобразить его

Далее код рисования многоугольника

```
int count, num_Tochka;
Graphics gr;
Point[] pt;
double sum;
double d;
bool move_Tochka;
Pen pen_shtrih;
Pen pen_lastik;
Pen pen_base;

double DistanceTo(int i)
{
    double d;
    d = (pt[i].X - pt[i+1].X) * (pt[i].X - pt[i+1].X) + (pt[i].Y - pt[i+1].Y) * (pt[i].Y - pt[i+1].Y);
    return Math.Sqrt(d);

    //   return d;
}

double Perimetr()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count-1; i++)
    {
        sum += DistanceTo(i);
        //sum += Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((pt[i + 1].X – pt[i].X), 2) + Math.Pow((pt[i + 1].Y - pt[i].Y), 2));
    }
    d = (pt[0].X - pt[count -1].X) * (pt[0].X - pt[count -1].X) + (pt[0].Y - pt[count -1].Y) * (pt[0].Y - pt[count -1].Y);

    sum +=  Math.Sqrt(d);
    return sum;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gr.Clear(Color.White);
    Array.Resize(ref pt, 1);
    count = 0;
    move_Tochka = false;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gr = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
    pen_base = new Pen(Color.Tomato, 3);
    pen_lastik = new Pen(Color.White, 3);
}

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (move_Tochka != true)
    {
         pt[count] = e.Location;
         listBox1.Items.Add(pt[count]);
         gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, pt[count].X - 2, pt[count].Y - 2, 5, 5);
         count += 1;
         Array.Resize(ref pt, count + 1);
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void pictureBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Array.Resize(ref pt, count);
    gr.DrawPolygon(pen_base, pt);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
         if((Math.Abs(pt[i].X-e.X)<=5)&&((Math.Abs(pt[i].Y-e.Y)<=5)))
         {
              num_Tochka = i;
              move_Tochka = true;
         }
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(move_Tochka&e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
         gr.DrawPolygon(pen_lastik, pt);
         pt[num_Tochka] = e.Location;
         gr.DrawPolygon(pen_base, pt);
         label1.Text = "perimetr = " + Math.Round(Perimetr(), 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: И в чём собственно вопрос?

Comment: перечисленные вами действия для многоугольника требуют дополнительных условий, вокруг какой именно точки поворачивать (как и кто ее задает)? относительно какой линии отразить (тот же вопрос)? С масштабированием немного проще. И собственно что вы уже попробовали кроме рисования самого многоугольника?

Comment: По текущему коду: замените `Point[]` на `List<Point>`, он ресайзится реже и умнее, производительность будет выше. Еще можно заменить ваш массив точек на `GraphicsPath`. он "из коробки" умеет все что вы перечислили, только придется разобраться с матрицами преобразований.

Comment: Смотрите методы класса `Graphics`: `ScaleTransform`, `RotateTransform` и т. п.